# Are Delphi FireDAC shared connections thread safe

Tags: delphi, thread-safety, firedac

I'm using Delphi 10.2.3 w/ FireDAC on a Firebird DB.  I have an event history table that gets updated asynchronously with external device events.  If the device count is high and the events frequent, there can be concurrent calls to the method that updates the DB with the event.  I'd like to wrap the update in a thread using a shared connection to accommodate the potential for these collisions.  I just want to confirm that FireDAC shared connections are thread-safe?

Comment: No. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Multithreading_(FireDAC)

Comment: OK, thanks.  I'll switch to pooled connections.

Comment: I cannot get pooled connections to work - if I set Pooled=True, it throws an exception about extra parameters, including in the connection def editor in the IDE.  Is this a limitation of Firebird?

Comment: Found the problem: the connection definition had a `Driver=FB` line.  Removing that and letting the FireDAC code set the driver type allowed the connection.

Answer (score 0):

No. An excerpt from the Delphi 10 online help topic **[Multithreading (FireDAC)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Multithreading_(FireDAC))**:

> after a thread opens a query and until its processing is finished, the
> application cannot use this query and the connection objects in
> another thread. Similarly, after a thread starts a transaction and
> until the transaction is finished, the application cannot use this
> transaction and the connection objects in another thread.